# Resolving method name from inner class

Tags: java

```
public class X {

    public void close() {
      // ...
    }

    public class XInputStream extends InputStream {

        public void f() {
           close(); // are we calling close() on InputStream or X??
        }
    }
}
```

1. The compiler is fine with this sort of thing, so obviously it knows which method to call. What exactly is the rule in the language spec for resolving this?
2. Other than renaming my `close()` method, are there any steps I could take to make this code more readable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant portion of the JLS is [§6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1). Basically, the compiler will look in the smallest scope possible for the correct method. The first scope it checks is in `XInputStream`. It finds a `close` method, so it calls that one.

To make it more readable, you can qualify your method calls: `this.close()` to call `InputStream::close` or `X.this.close()` to call `X::close`.

Comment: +1, I was writing pretty much the same thing - key being "smallest scope possible."

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an inner class:

```
public class XInputStream extends InputStream
```

the close() method that is called here is the one that is found in the InputStream class that you are extending from.

Also, you have to wrap the close() method with a try-catch, and any class that extends InputStream must  either be declared abstract or implement the method read().